# Noun for person that you "suck up" to

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, epithet-requests

I am looking for a general term for a person that people "suck up" to or ask favors of often so that they can advance themselves. Essentially, I am looking for a term that would describe a person in power who can give people opportunities, and is also broad enough to encompass multiple areas (academic, government, workforce, etc.).

Comment: If you want something colloquial, that person could be said to be your **meal ticket**. "a person or thing that is depended on as a source of money, success, etc."

Comment: Wouldn't everyone in any position in power be someone who is the recipient of flattery? Can you clarify how *a person you suck up to* differs from a person in any position of power (e.g., boss, supervisor, big wig, etc.)?

Comment: Probably too informal and/or sexist, but “the Godfather” and “the Man” often get sucked [up to].

Comment: A single word for those whom are being "brown nosed"? Good question.

Comment: @Mazura Seeing it from that end of the spectrum could perhaps lead to “a nose-browner!” Anyway, I agree, it’s a good question that got my +1 a bit earlier.

Comment: So the people doing the sucking are the *suckers*; I guess that makes those who are sucked, the *suckees*? (Unless of course the who are sucked are fooled by the suckophantic behavior, in which case **they** would be the *suckers*.)

Comment: @Sven Yargs You might call this person your boss.

Comment: @Mazura: "who are". Never "whom are". That is not English.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I looked up *whom* to post that and still got it wrong. It's hard to English.

Comment: @Mazura: it's actually exceptionally easy to English. Those people have misled you. There is exactly one rule, and it is very simple. When in doubt, use *who*. That's it. If you don't know what to use, use *who*. You will be correct every single time. Every single time. And the best part is, the same rule applies to a whole lot of stuff in English. Like semicolons, say. If you think that's hard, try German, Russian, or Finnish. Those have like, no rules at all. Impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the point of view of the sycophant, who would use a complimentary term, and perhaps from the point of view of others, who might not be so inclined, the person flattered is someone they hope to make their

> **benefactor**
>   A person who supports or helps a person....

(*Collins*)

Although now tinged with archaism,

> **patron**
>   1. One that supports, protects, or champions someone....

(*American Heritage*)

might suit your purposes better than 'benefactor'.

Answer (score 0):

So the person who is doing the sucking up is a brown nose or [*sycophant*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant), which according to MW is:

> a person who praises powerful people in order to get their approval

So *powerful people* are the receivers.  Looking for synonyms there, MacMillian gives you

> magnate, VIP, figure, prime mover, leading light, mogul, eminence, etc.

which all have different denotations, and don't particularly match. I also searched for a generic term for someone who receives a compliment, and came up with a blank.  So the relationship doesn't seem to be one-to-one. There isn't a single word because a sycophant may address several areas. If it's a business, maybe magnate, or even boss comes into play. In other contexts, the other words might work. It seems you'd have to pick something to match the context.

Answer (score 0):

Consider, ***wire-puller***

> *also* (*esp. BrEng)* [string-puller](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/avoir%20le%20bras%20long): one who uses secret or underhanded means to influence the acts of a person or organization.
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wire%E2%80%93puller)
>
> **pull strings/wires**
>
> : to secretly use the influence that you have over important people in order to get something or to help someone *I may be able to pull a few strings for you if you need the document urgently.*
>
> [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+strings)
>
> **pull**
>
> Influence; special power or favor; clout: *irregularities and instances of political pull* (1886+)
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pull)

Answer (score 0):

Upon observing sycophantic and deferential behavior directed at a certain individual, one might say figuratively that said person was ***"at the top of the food-chain".***